# MySQL Group By assistance need it

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I try to craete a randomized banner plugin for my WordPress installation, and also I like to extract some statistic information from my banners.

To perform that task I have create a table with the following signature:

```
CREATE TABLE `bb_banner_statistics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

where `post_id` is the banner ID, `event` is the event I like to track (ie. viewed, hovered, clicked, etc), `value` just take the value "1" (I did this for easy sumirization of the specific event type), and `created` that is the date time of the event.

So, in example the table can contain values like the following:

```
|---------------------------------------------------|
| ID | POST_ID | EVENT | VALUE | CREATED            |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 62      | view  | 1     | 2014-4-12 11:45:12 |
| 2  | 63      | view  | 1     | 2014-4-12 11:45:12 |
| 3  | 64      | view  | 1     | 2014-4-12 11:45:12 |
| 4  | 62      | hover | 1     | 2014-4-12 11:46:18 |
| 5  | 63      | hover | 1     | 2014-4-12 11:46:22 |
| 6  | 63      | click | 1     | 2014-4-12 11:46:23 |
| 7  | 62      | hover | 1     | 2014-4-12 11:46:23 |
| 8  | 62      | view  | 1     | 2014-4-13 09:20:17 |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

So the question is, how can I group my data in order to get the total views performed for each banner for each day, the total clicks and the total hover events ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select date(created) as thedate, post_id,
       sum(event = 'click') as numclicks,
       sum(event = 'view') as numviews,
       sum(event = 'hover') as numhovers
from bb_banner_statistics
group by date(created), post_id;
```